# Component of the force, about vector, given AB= 2100N, Find the Fx,Fy and Fz.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

I think i need to find the angle, to calculate the Fx,Fy and Fz.
But what should i do to the unit vectors?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest try to answer this problem along the hint provided. For that you'll have to find the angles $A\hat{B}O$ and $A\hat{B}C$ and $B\hat{A}O$. Can you continue?